# Getting ng-class to work

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template

When I test `ng-class` in the w3schools.com [Try It page](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-class), everything works as the documentation says. When I try it in a bare-bones Angular 2 app, I get no joy.

Here are my steps. In a Terminal window:

1. `ng new classTest`
2. `cd classTest`
3. `ng serve`

In a text editor:
**app.component.css**

```
.red {
  color: #f00;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1 ng-class="{'red': true}">
  {{title}}
</h1>
```

Result: the text **app works!** appears in black, not red. I have tried a number of other variations, such as `ng-class="'red'"`, in the w3schools.com [Try It page](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-class), the text goes as red as you please.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's AngularJS example, syntax for `NgClass` directive in Angular 2 is the following:

```
<h1 [ngClass]="{'red': true}">
    {{title}}
</h1>
```

You can read more about `NgClass` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html).